# Looking for the Clear Method in Xamarin BaseAdapter

Tags: android, xamarin

I am looking for the Xamarin Android BaseAdapter Clear() method. In native Android there is a method that is exposed in ArrayAdapter that you can use to clear a derived adapter before you start adding items to the list.

I cannot find this in Xamarin.Android BaseAdapter and this is leading to loading duplicate List items in my ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android BaseAdapter uses a List object to store it's data. You must have a reference to it in your adapter. Simply clear the List (i.e. mList.clear, then call mBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter. If you need to do it from outside the adapter, then create a method, such as:

```
public void clearAdapterData() {
    mList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You really shouldn't be clearing your adapter though everytime you make an update. Instead you should cycle through you List objects and update ones already present in the list, and add unique items to your list. Then of course call notifyDataSetChanged()